# How many quantifiers to state P!=NP in Peano arithmetic?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity

It is said that P!=NP is an arithmetical statement, also that it is of order two, that is we can state is as $\forall_p \exists_i \text{(polynomial-time turing machine number $p$ fails to solve 3SAT instance number $i$})$. Can we write that sentence using only arithmetical and logical operators? How to do it? If not, what's the minimum number of quantifiers possible?

I currently can't state it using any number of quantifiers, and I heard it's possible, so I want to know how, but I wasn't able to find a reference. Additionally, I was just curious about the minimum number of quantifiers.

I don't need a detailed construction for this specific question, I could figure it out based on an explanation of encoding computation in arithmetic.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser thank you, I've added some context, does it suffice?

Comment: The standard way of encoding computational questions in arithmetic is via [Kleene's T-predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate), and this leads to the "obvious" translation of $\mathsf{P\not=NP}$ being $\Pi_2$.